# Table layout with %, Auto and px

Tags: css, http, tablelayout, css-grid

I am trying to achieve the following table layout:

[image]

Third column fits to content in the cells.
The last one is fixed to 100px.
The two first columns share the rest space with the proportion.

Comment: what do you mean when you say `col1 = 200%` and `col2 = 100%`? 100% of what?

Comment: Yep, it should be noted that 100% and 200% -> the rest of space should be devided with such proportion

Comment: But then also you have an auto-sized part for `col3`?

Comment: @pandorym yes, col3 should have width to fit content in cells

Comment: Looks like the only way is CSS Grid Layout